# Command Line Clipboard Access

Tags: command-line, clipboard

I'm building a command line tool in order to make some of my tasks more efficient.  I need to be able to write content to the clipboard, but for some reason it's not working for me.

I've tried installing both `xclip` and `xsel`, but both have the same behavior: they can read/write to the clipboard fine, but I cannot access it from the main Ubuntu GUI.

I've also tried it in the terminal...

```
echo "hello" | xclip
```

Then if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I get my original clipboard entry, not "hello".  But, if I try to grab the content from `xclip`, it works fine.

The main goal is get the content pastable into Firefox or whatever other GUI-based programs I'm using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, there are a few different clipboards in X :) The one `xclip` copies text into by default is "selection buffer" - usually you just select some text with your mouse and then can paste it with middle mouse button. This buffer is separate from the one from which you can paste with Ctrl-Shift-V.

Try

```
echo "hello" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

also, see

```
man xclip
```

for more details about xclip

Comment: FYI , also can be shortened to `xclip -sel clip` . i personally use that all the time

Comment: God why is this so confusing, why wasn't one clipboard enough, see `man xclip` `-selection specify which X selection to use, options are "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY  (default),  "secondary"  for XA_SECONDARY or "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD`

Comment: It seems that the frequent action is to "select some text with your mouse". Is it possible to the same action with keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

To make it easier for myself I created an alias for `xclip` in order to mimic the functionality of `pbcopy` and and `pbpaste` in Mac OS X.

```
sudo apt-get install xclip -y
```

Then edit your `~/.bashrc` to add aliases:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add these new lines (you could put them at the end of the file):

```
alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'
```

Save and exit, then open a new shell or run `source ~/.bashrc` to use the aliases.

[My blog post](http://garywoodfine.com/use-pbcopy-on-ubuntu/) contains further details.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use the utilities wxcopy and wxpaste from windowmaker, but recent Linux versions (or X versions) seem to have broken them - I suspect security has been tightened up and they have not been updated to match.  E.g. you could do things like:

```bsh
echo fred | wxcopy | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | wxpaste
```

to get the output FRED.  (It's a contrived example, since you'd get the same thing without the final wxpaste, but I think it gives the flavour of what you can achieve.)

However, you can achieve the same effect using the "xcb" package, which is incredibly lightweight and also provides a tiny (summarised) visual display of 8 clipboards.

I wrote a pair of shell scripts wcopy/wpaste years ago, to make wxcopy/wxpaste a bit more pleasant to my taste.  I updated them tonight to work with either wxcopy/wxpaste or xcb.  That makes them a bit more complex than they need to be, but I'll paste them in here - hopefully they're not too long for this forum.

Here's wcopy:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#
# Provide some enhancements to the wxcopy command, which copies standard input
# to an X11 clipboard text buffer.
#
# Allow copying from stdin to any of the cutbuffers.  Note that they are
# indexed counting from 0.
#
# Author: Luke Kendall
#

if [ `uname -s` = "Darwin" ]
then
    WXCOPY=pbcopy
    WXPASTE=pbpaste
else
    WXCOPY=wxcopy
    WXPASTE=wxpaste
    BUFSPEC="-cutbuffer"
    xcb -p 0 > /tmp/wc$$
    if echo "fred$$" | wxcopy -cutbuffer 0 && [ `wxpaste` = "fred$$" ]
    then
        : # Great, they're actually working.  Not common on modern Linuxes.
        echo "working" > $HOME/.wcopyok
    else
        rm -f $HOME/.wcopyok
        WXCOPY="xcb -s"
        WXPASTE="xcb -p"
        BUFSPEC=
    fi
    xcb -s 0 < /tmp/wc$$
fi

unset WXARGS
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    $WXCOPY ${WXCOPY_DEFS:-0}
else
    MYNAME=`basename $0`
    USAGE="usage: $MYNAME [ [0-9]... ] [$WXCOPY's args]"
    numlist=true
    for n
    do
        if $numlist && expr "x$n" : 'x[0-9][0-9]*$' > /dev/null
        then
            NUMARGS="$NUMARGS $n"
        else
            numlist=false
            if [ "x$n" = "x-h" ]
            then
                echo "$USAGE" >&2
                exit 0
            else
                WXARGS="$WXARGS $n"
            fi
        fi
    done
    set - $NUMARGS
    $WXCOPY $WXCOPY_DEFS $WXARGS $BUFSPEC $1
    ORIG="$1"
    shift
    for n
    do
        $WXPASTE $BUFSPEC $ORIG | $WXCOPY $WXCOPY_DEFS $WXARGS $BUFSPEC $n
    done
fi
```

And here's wpaste:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#
# Provide some enhancements to the wxpaste command, which pastes from X11
# clipboard text buffers to standard output.
#
# Allow pasting to stdout from any of the cutbuffers.  Note that they are
# indexed counting from 0.
#
# Author: Luke Kendall
#

if [ `uname -s` = "Darwin" ]
then
    WXCOPY=pbcopy
    WXPASTE=pbpaste
else
    WXCOPY=wxcopy
    WXPASTE=wxpaste
    BUFSPEC="-cutbuffer"
    if [ -s $HOME/.wcopyok ]
    then
        : # Great, they're actually working.  Not common on modern Linuxes.
    else
        WXCOPY="xcb -s"
        WXPASTE="xcb -p"
        BUFSPEC=
    fi
fi

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    $WXPASTE ${WXPASTE_DEFS:-0}
else
    MYNAME=`basename $0`
    USAGE="usage: $MYNAME [ [0-9]... ] [$WXPASTE's args]"
    for n
    do
        if expr "x$n" : 'x[0-9][0-9]*$' > /dev/null
        then
            NUMARGS="$NUMARGS $n"
        elif [ "x$n" = "x-h" ]
        then
            echo "$USAGE" >&2
            exit 0
        else
            WXARGS="$WXARGS $n"
        fi
    done
    set - $NUMARGS
    : echo "Num args: $#"
    for n
    do
        : echo "Doing: $WXPASTE $WXPASTE_DEFS $WXARGS $BUFSPEC $n"
        $WXPASTE $WXPASTE_DEFS $WXARGS $BUFSPEC $n
    done
fi
```

If anyone's interested, I wrote man pages for the scripts, too - but you can probably find them (they're still valid) by googling wcopy.1x and wpaste.1x

Comment: You can edit your answer to add hyperlinks to the manpages. (You should be able to add up to 2 links, even though you're a new AU user.)