# how can I paste copied-clipboard text to a file from terminal?

Tags: 12.04, clipboard

I have copied something from Internet and I want that copied text to get copied to a file. But how can I copy that text without using mouse or any command like Ctrl+V. I want to do this from terminal. How can I do that in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Have a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/110347/command-line-clipboard-access

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `xclip`.
For writing clipboard to file, overriding existing content:

```
xclip -o > /path/to/file.txt
```

or for appending clipboard to file:

```
xclip -o >> /path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: Good one. +1 from me.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want (or you can't) install extra software, you can do it with `cat`

```
cat > /path/to/file.txt
```

after this the terminal waits user input, so you can paste from your clipboard:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

And exit `cat` with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

I learned this while watching:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDddKmdLEdg

Comment: This answer worked on mac terminal. Thank you.

Comment: Finally, a solution that works over ssh!

Comment: This is the WAY BETTER answer!!!

Comment: right-click to paste, instead of Ctrl + Shift + v, worked for me (Ubuntu terminal on WSL), but otherwise great solution, installed xclip for nothing as it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

copy to clipboard then

```
xsel -o >> note.txt
```

but it not include new line "\n"

用件、用例(scenario):
I input some Japanese 言葉 on google.translate.com
then I'd like to take a note to save input history for review it later.

Answer (score -1):

Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C`  to Copy

Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `V`  to Paste

Comment: "how can I copy that text without using mouse or any command like Ctrl+V"