# How can I pipe the output of a bash or shell command to the clip board?

Tags: gnome, bash, clipboard, accessibility, pipe

In order to minimize mouse usage (accessibility and health reasons), how can I pipe the standard out to the OS clip board?

That is, I'd like to do something like:

`$ drush uli | copy-this-to-clipbaord`

`$ drush uli > copy-this-to-clipbaord`

Possible?

Comment: Start with `man -k clipboard`

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110347/command-line-clipboard-access and a few other :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install [xsel](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xsel/) either through the above link or through the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

To copy the output of a command use:

```
*command* | xsel -ib
```

An example:

```
$ drush uli | xsel -ib
```

You can make it simpler by editing (create it if you don't already have it with `touch ~/.bash_aliases`) your `~/.bash_aliases` file.

Add this line to it: `alias clipboard = 'xsel -ib'` (you can use any name, not just `clipboard`).

Once you've done so you can use: `*command* | clipboard`

Answer (score 5):

I use xclip.

Example:

```
bashscript.sh | xclip -sel clip
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xsel` in just that way:

```
xsel -i -b >/dev/null
```

- Option `-i` (`--input`) makes it read input from standard input
- Option `-b` (`--clipboard`) makes it use the clipboard buffer instead the selection or one of the less commonly further buffers.
- `>/dev/null` is hiding some annoying error message - not shure that can occur with these options set.

So, why not try

```
drush uli | xsel -i -b
```

and tell whether paste from clipboard pastes the right text!
I left out the part hiding errors for testing.